# Threads - why exception is thrown at runtime?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am confused at the output of the following program

```
public class ChicksYack implements Runnable {
  Chicks c ;
  public static void main(String[] args){
    new ChicksYack().go();
  }

  void go(){
    c= new Chicks();
    new Thread(new ChicksYack()).start();
    new Thread(new ChicksYack()).start();
  }

  public void run() {
    c.yack(Thread.currentThread().getId());
  }
}

class Chicks{
  synchronized void yack(long id){
    for(int x = 1 ; x < 3 ; x++){
      System.out.print(id + " ");
      Thread.yield();
    }
  }
}
```

The program throws `NullPointerException` at run-time. Will the value of Chicks variable c won't be shared on thread-1 and thread-2 stack. I know i am making a pretty silly mistake but pretty confused. Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: A shot in the dark: initialize `Chick c` in the second line of your code listing? Also your stacktrace would help.

Comment: c isn't shared among instances. You create one instance in your main(), set the c of that one in go(), then you create two new instances which will have null values in their c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're ensuring that there is an instance of `Chicks` in each instance of `ChicksYack`, then you need to move the line:

```
c= new Chicks();
```

into a constructor e.g.

```
public ChicksYack() {
    c= new Chicks();
}
```

and change the type of the member variable from `Chicks c` to `final Chicks c`; otherwise you are not guaranteed that you will see it fully constructed in the threads. Adding the `final` keywoard ensures that:

> When the **constructor exits**, the values of **final** fields are **guaranteed to be visible** to other threads accessing the constructed object. (ref: [Javamex.com](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_final.shtml) website)

As is, you're creating two more instances of `ChicksYack` that don't have the `c` member initialized.

Now if you're intending on having only a single instance of `Chicks` shared amongst all the instances of `ChicksYack`, then you need to declare it as `static` e.g.

```
static Chicks c;
```

Comment: +0 While this is a good idea, the field has to be `final` to guarantee it will be seen.  Just moving it won't make any difference.

Comment: @Petesh i realized the issue. It was a pretty silly question. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

you have three instances of ChicksYack and not-static field for Chicks.

I think you should change go method to something like this

```
void go(){
  c= new Chicks();
  new Thread(this).start();
  new Thread(this).start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The program throws NullPointerException at run-time. Will the value of Chicks variable c won't be shared on thread-1 and thread-2 stack.

Nothing in a computer really happen immediately.  If you believed anything was instant, forget that.  This means that while a thread can update a field, it takes time to be visible to other threads.

There is a number of exceptions, one is using `volatile` fields (It is still not instant instead it waits for any update) and the other is any field set before a thread is started.  If this program really throws an NPE for you I would suspect you have a bug in your JVM.  I would make sure you have the latest version